# Black screen in inner preferenceScreen

Tags: android

My `PreferenceActivity` contains a nested `PreferenceScreen` in another `PreferenceScreen` and I'm applying a theme to my `PrefenceActivity` that changes the background color. However when I open the nested `PreferenceScreen` I get a black background and I cannot see the options.

This happens with android 2.1 , but it does not happen with android 1.6.
Any ideas on how this can be corrected?

Comment: could you please provide some logs/more data?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found a way to do it but it quite a hack.

This is my `prefs.xml`

```
<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="@string/hello">

    <CheckBoxPreference
        key="pref_update_key"
        android:title="@string/hello"
        android:summaryOn="@string/hello"
        android:summaryOff="@string/hello"
        android:persistent="true"
        android:defaultValue="false" />

</PreferenceCategory>

<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:key="pref_second_preferencescreen_key" android:title="@string/hello">
        <CheckBoxPreference
        key="pref_update_key"
        android:title="@string/hello"
        android:summaryOn="@string/hello"
        android:summaryOff="@string/hello"
        android:persistent="true"
        android:defaultValue="false" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

And this is my code for the class that `extends PreferenceActivity`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.prefs);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.background);

    PreferenceScreen b = (PreferenceScreen) findPreference("pref_second_preferencescreen_key");
    b.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            PreferenceScreen a = (PreferenceScreen) preference;
            a.getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.background);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: not working for me tried on 1.6 and 2.3.4 both still show a black screen.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me: Simply set a list style:

```
<style name="Theme.Preferences" parent="android:Theme.Light" >
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/lightListView</item>
</style>
<style name="lightListView">
    <item name="android:background">#ffffff<item>
</style>
```

Comment: worked for me, too. The problem with this approach arises if you use a custom background drawable.

Comment: Very elegant solution!

Comment: Don't forget to change the last end item tag to </item>

Comment: It's sad that StackOverflow doesn't allow suggesting edits which contain only one symbol change.

Answer (score 3):

Workaround:

1) Prepare 2 PreferenceScreen xml's instead of sub PreferenceScreen using;

2) Add secondary PreferenceScreen Activity to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.PreferenceActivity2"
          android:label="Issue4611"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

3) For show secondary PreferenceScreen use  in your first PreferenceScreen:

```
<PreferenceScreen android:key="key1"
                  android:title="1 Item"
                  android:summary="">
    <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:targetPackage="com.example"
            android:targetClass="com.example.PreferenceActivity2"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

[Example](http://bit.ly/fJLuCy)

Answer (score 0):

**Macarse**'s answer is perfect, 
I was searching for classic white background so I changed this line in his answer:

```
a.getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.background);
```

to:

```
a.getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.white);
```

and it works nicely.

Comment: Is doesn't work for a second level of preference screen