# android ListPreference and Preference item background image and text gravity

Tags: android, customization, preferences, preferenceactivity

my preference activity contains a CheckboxPreference, ListPreference, and a sub Preference screen containing 5 CheckboxPreferences.

i managed to solve the problem of inner PreferenceScreen background using this :
[Black screen in inner preferenceScreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164862/black-screen-in-inner-preferencescreen)

but i have more problems i could not solve:

1- i need to change the background of each preference item in both PrefernceScreens, i tried the following but it did not work

Preference ax=findPreference("ck_pref");

View v = ax.getView(null, null);

v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rowbackground);

i tried to use a custom layout file form the solution provided in the link below:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/d3bb7af55dba7d8d

it changed the background of the textviews but not the whole row

2-  i tried to change the text gravity of the items in the ListPreference and also no success.

any suggestions will be appreciated, thanks in advance.